# Height vector and its length in a triangle

Tags: trigonometry, triangles

I have a triangle with the points $v_1, v_2$ and $v_3$. I want to find the normal vector and its length on $a$ $\left(v_2-v_1\right)$. My idea, that technically would work was:

$a = v_2 - v_1$ 
$b = v_3 - v_1$ 
$sqr\_magnitude\_a = \sum{a^2}$ 
$dot\_ab = \left(a \cdot b\right)$ 
$l = dot\_ab \div sqr\_magnitude\_a$ 
$c = a \cdot l$ 
$cb = b-c$ 
$l1\_cb = \sqrt{\sum cb^2}$

However, the authors proposed a different solution, which is much more complex and involves an unnecessary $\varepsilon$ (which would be fine if the results could be $0$, but that is not possible in all cases), and I cannot get behind why they did that in such a complicated way:

$\varepsilon = 1e-6$ 
$a = v_2 - v_1$ 
$b = v_3 - v_1$ 
$sqr\_magnitude\_a = \sum{a^2}$ 
$sqr\_magnitude\_b = \sum{b^2}$ 
$magnitude\_a = \sqrt{sqr\_magnitude\_a + \varepsilon}$ 
$magnitude\_b = \sqrt{sqr\_magnitude\_b + \varepsilon}$ 
$dot\_ab = \left(a \cdot b\right)$ 
$cos = dot\_ab \div \left(magnitude\_a \cdot magnitude\_b + \varepsilon\right)$ 
$sin = \sqrt{1 - cos^2 + \varepsilon}$

$l = dot\_ab \div sqr\_magnitude\_a$ 
$c = a \cdot l$ 
$cb = b-c$ 
$l1\_cb = magnitude\_b \cdot sin$

Can anyone explain what the thought process behind the second solution is? There should not be a difference between our solutions (despite different results which I attribute to the usage of the $\varepsilon$) and I do not understand, why they proposed their formula the way they did.

Comment: Indeed, if you set eps=0, you should agree exactly. It looks like this book assumes some small error, perhaps from measurement? What is the context of the chapter?

Comment: The expression "the normal vector and its length on a $(v_2-v_1)$" is not standard : do you mean the altitude dropped from $v_3$ to opposite side $[v_1,v_2]$ ?

Comment: Another non understandable statement : "sqr_magnitude_a $=\Sigma a^2$". What are you summing with this sign $\Sigma$ ?

Comment: I'm sorry for the misunderstandings and incorrect used terms. Since the original problem is a coding problem with an underlying maths problem rather than a maths problem itself I tried to map the code and the used language into a math context to the best of my abilities.

Comment: @AaronGoldsmith the context is to compute the angle between adjoint triangles in order to regularize a 3D mesh deformation. This process does not involve any measurement. But thank you, I was really doubting myself on the maths here and if there is no mathematical reason, there cannot really be any other explanation other than the authors came to this conclusion via trial and error.

Comment: @JeanMarie I'm sorry if I've used the wrong terms, as explained above I tried to map programming terms into a math context. Yes, I meant the altitude, thanks for correcting me on that. With the $\sum a^2$ I meant the sum of the squared vector components; e.g.: for a 3D vector $a0^2 + a1^2 +a2^2$

Comment: I found sqr_ magnitude_a to be self-explanatory and the notation to be standard enough.